# How to access User Control graph dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a main form and a user control(with graphs). And I'm updating the graphs dynamically.

```
 void foo(int i)
        {

            MainForm MF = (MainForm)MainForm.ActiveForm;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.userGraph.updatesomething(i);
               // usergraph is the user control which has graphs
            }

        }
```

The problem is when I navigate out of the main form I cant update the graph. Is there any other way where I can write into the user control even if its not the active form?
If I create a new instance, the previous updates on the graph will be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved by using `Application.OpenForms["Name of the Form"]` method.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution i think would be to pass a reference of the usercontrol between the form and the user control. Create a field in the user control, for example;

```
public Form formExample{get;set;}
```

And when you instantiate the usercontrol originally, pass the reference as a parameter;

```
userControl usercontrol = new userControl();
usercontrol.formExample = this;
//passing this from the original form will pass a reference of it.
```

This way you can now access the graph on the Form from the user control. If you want to do it the other way around, i.e. access a graph on the user control from the form, just pass references the other way around. I free-typed this, but i think the syntax is all there!

Comment: You mean to pass all the values to the user control?

Comment: Can you explain the situation more please? Where is the graph placed with respect to the form / user control, and where do the values come from / where do you want to end up? By passing a reference of the form to the user control, you should be able to access any values the form has, as long as the modifiers permit (i.e. public variables)

Comment: I have one 'main' form and 2 user controls 'ValueGenerator' and 'GraphControl'. I want to draw graph from Value Generator and using main control as the active form i am drawing the graph. What u r telling is to pass the graph itself as reference? to the value generator?